# Adjusting the UiTableview hight in IB so the the table its able to scroll all the rows

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a UITableView that is cutting off the last row and a half. I assume this is due to the face that I am using a navigation controller. What I can't figure out is how to adjust the height of the TableView so that it works on both iPhone 4 and 5's. If I adjust the height in IB to fit the iPhone 4, I have a large gap on the bottom of the iPhone 5. I would think there is some automatic way of doing this, but nothing I am trying seems to be working.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted. There is not code that I am able to show since I am using IB for the layout. I attempted to describe the issue I am having in a clear and precise way. I have been looking at forms and googling the same issue, but I most find answer that relate to set up a "pre scroll" before the view loads.. which is not what my issue is. I asked the question here with hope that some one had some insight as to what my issue might be. I'm using xCode 5 with auto-layout, but my tableView still does not resize for the iPhone 4 screen.

Comment: Describe how your constraints are set up. Do you use a height constraint (which you shouldn't) or have you set up a constraint between the bottom of the tableView and the bottom of the parentView (which you should)?

Comment: Matthias,Thank you so much! I converted this app from a tableviewcontroller to using a table view inside a view controller and I completely forgot about setting the constraints! Again thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout - [Official Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)...

Also, if you're using a `UITableViewController` on the storyboard, this will solve your problem (with or without navigation controller, which is unrelated).  If you're using a `UITableView` on a regular `UIViewController`, however, the best answer is auto-layout.

Comment: Thanks nhgrif, i am am using auto-layout which is what I can't figure out.